# Increase Screen Name Length

Tags: control-panel, screen-name

The screen_name member field is limited to 50 characters in the CP...is there a way to increase this? We have some company names for Screen Names that are longer than 50 characters.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since checking for lenght is not part of screen name validation in EE, I guess you only need to change the property of database column in exp_members table to allow, e.g. 100 characters